# Unable to load nginx websites on LAN when remotely connected via OpenVPN

Tags: nginx, networking, openvpn, reverse-proxy, pfsense

Okay here is the basic issue:
I can't connect to my HTML webpage (A Docker container's config - e.g. Unifi controller, SABnzbd, etc. - these are all behind a reverse proxy) when I'm connected to my LAN via a remote connection.  When I'm locally connected to my LAN all the webpages load.  When I'm outside my LAN, anywhere in the world (I travel for work) the webpages load.  I CAN connect to webpages that are not behind the reverse proxy while remotely connected to my VPN (e.g. unRAID GUI and pfsense GUI).

Some background on my setup:
I have an unRAID server with Docker containers including one running nginx which I have setup to act as a reverse proxy for each Dockers webpage.  My router is a pfsense box that I've added a rule to allow my reverse proxy as well as the OpenVPN remote connection.  My LAN addresses are all 10.10.x.x and the VPN is set to use 172.16.0.0/24 as the "Tunnel Network" (my first instinct is that the conflict may be here) and "IPv4 Local networks" 10.0.0.0/8

I'm not sure if that's enough info for anyone to help me find the issue but I would really appreciate any help.

UPDATES:  I am able to reach the webpages when using the ip through the vpn tunnel.  After doing a tcpdump I do see packets reaching the port on the container hosting the webpage but fewer packets when it fails through the vpn than when testing outside the vpn so I'm not sure how useful that data point is.

The most interesting data I've found is that when I do a tracert for the full domain name it is unreachable right prior to the vpn server ip and if I do another tracert using the ip address it completes the trace.  When the vpn is down tracert finds the route no problem whether using domain name or an ip like it should.

Comment: Can you reach your internal website via its IP? If you can, it's probably a DNS issue. Running a packet capture on the nginx box (something like "tcpdump -i any port <reverse proxy port>) should help you understand if traffic is even reaching your Nginx reverse proxy. Also, do you have any ACL configured in Nginx?

Comment: Yes I am able to reach the destination when using the IP.  I don't know if there's ACL, I've setup a pretty basic preconfigured NGINX docker that had config files for each container I just enabled them and put the correct ip/port in the config file and voila it works.

Comment: I finally was able to get tcpdump working on the server so that I could monitor traffic.  I see traffic on port 444 on the ip for the container both times I tested.  Once I tested from outside my VPN connection navigating to a URL that is setup with the reverse proxy and it pulls the webpage and there's a ton of packets flowing.  Then I captured when I tried to go to the same URL inside the VPN and it was less packets and the page wouldn't load.  I can't make heads or tails of what the packets mean and there's nothing showing in the nginx error.log during either test.